# Workflow rule execution

Tags: trigger, custom-object, workflow, formula-field

I have a parent object - Opportunity and a child custom object - Child_Opp. I have workflow rule created on Opportunity Object. I have a field in Opportunity object which refers to a field in Child_Opp object. Field_opp in Opportunity has a value of Child_Opp__r.Field_child_opp.

So basically in my opportunity I have a field(Field_opp) which gets its value from a field(Field_child_opp) in Child_Opp object. My questions is can I include the field(Field_opp) in rule criteria of my workflow rule( created in Opportunity Object) . When I change the Field_child_opp, the workflow rule should execute . Can this be possible?

Comment: Workflow rules on a target object `Opportunity` can never refer, in the rule criteria, to child objs `Child_Opp` ;

Comment: Hi , Any work around to solve this?

Comment: do you have a RSF or DLRS RSF in Opportunity upon child?

Comment: I guess I have RSF in Opportunity which is based upon child. So I am using a formula field in Opportunity , the formula field has the value of the field from child like - childobject__r.child field__c.

Comment: But a formula in a parent can't refer to a child object.  I'm confused.

Comment: Oh ok, Can it be the other way? A formula field in child can have a value which refers to a field in Parent object? ex - Parentobje__r.Parentfield__c ?

Comment: Yes. That works fine.  If you use the formula builder, you can go up to 5 levels

Comment: But I want to implement something in the other way. I want to Parent field to be dependent on child field. From what you mentioned earlier - "ut a formula in a parent can't refer to a child object" , I guess its not possible to achieve this using point and click. Is there a work around possible like by creating a trigger/class to get the child field data from child object to a parent field?

Answer (score 0):

workflow can be created just for parent object.
Some-things cant be done with workflow try using process builder.
It would for sure help.